# Can't transforme sf feature on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, geospatial, r-sf, proj

In my shinyapp I try to transform a sf feature (with *EPSG:4326*) `sf::st_transform(sf_feature, crs = sf::st_crs(4839))`, but when deploying on shinyapps.io an error occurs:

> GDAL Error 1: No PROJ.4 translation for source SRS, coordinate transformation initialization has failed.

On the shinyapps.io server the geolibraries are as follows:

> GEOS 3.5.1, GDAL 2.2.2, PROJ 4.9.2

Comment: Are you using a free or paid account on shinyapps.io?

Comment: I'm using a free account. Everything is working fine, if I comment out this line.

Answer (score 0):

With a free account shinyapps.io blocks connections to other servers. As far as I know the sf package depends on GEOS, GDAS and other services to provide support for certain features (see the [web site](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/)). That is most likely the reason, why it does not work on a free shinyapps.io account.

Solutions are obvious:

- use other packages
- get a paid account

Aside from that I do not think there is much you can do.